# Learning how to use UML

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, uml

I just started C++ recently and now I am learning the concept of UML. Would UML be included in any C++ compilers or it should be run in a different software? What tools do I need to create an UML diagram?

Comment: UML has nothing to do with the compiler. You are asking for orthogonal things.

Comment: A UML editor like Sparx Enterprise Architect will do it.  But nobody really cares about UML.  You'd be better off learning how to design and write code well.  UML isn't necessary.  Read Fowler's "UML Distilled" - it's all the instruction you need.  A whiteboard and markers or paper and pencil are sufficient tools.

Comment: UML has nothing to do with C++, unless you're using some code-generation or code visualization tool. I guess, the most advanced tool for drawing UML is MS Visio, there are some [free alternatives](http://www.maketecheasier.com/5-best-free-alternatives-to-microsoft-visio/).

Comment: So how often people use UML in the industry?

Comment: @Khoily It's widely used in the industry, and a fixed part of the development process definitions of most bigger companies. Though UML doesn't necessarily directly relate to the details of the implementation in c++ code. For example UML models are very helpful to keep track on system level architectural views, and requirement analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UML is a visual language. You can use it to define or document software structure and behavior, but UML is not a programming language. The best source to learn UML is original UML superstructure document from OMG group (author of UML). You can download it from omg website for free. Here is a link: [UML Superstructure Specification](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/)

There are many software tools for creating UML models. (Free and commercially).
Some of tool are listed here: [Online tools for UML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877121/is-there-a-free-browser-based-uml-modelling-tool/6877298#6877298)

Answer (score 1):

There are many UML tools but I suggest you these two:
1- Visual paradigm
2- Rational rose

The visual paradigm software I prefer more because of it completeness comparing to rose. It also has a free edition. Just search the names and you can find their official web sites.

Answer (score 0):

I've never found UML to be useful outside of academic settings. It's especially useless for C++, where you'll often have little object-oriented programming in the first place but rather a lot of generic programming, free functions, lambdas, typedefs, legacy code and macros -- a world quite different from "clean" Java or C# architectures.

I know that UML has more features than arrows for IS-A and HAS-A, but will your programmer colleagues understand the diagrams if you use exotic notations going beyond these simple things? And if they don't, what's the point?

That's not to say that you shouldn't draw your software architecture on a piece of paper before even thinking about coding. You should spend A LOT of time drawing diagrams before touching the keyboard. But in the spirit of KISS, you'd do better with simple boxes and arrows describing the dependencies between your higher-level modules, rather than visualising the exact relationship between each and every class according to some obscure UML convention.

Comment: If UML is not useful, what tools do software engineers use to create a models before they write codes?

Comment: The most important tools are a pen and a piece of paper.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you try IBM Rhapsody (http://www.ibm.com/software/awdtools/rhapsody/). It's a very powerful tool that allows among others compiling UML into c/c++ compilable source code. It has a really great manual that will guide you through building of working applications using Rhapsody.

Comment: Hmm, I found rhapsody is too expensive for what's offered just right out of the box. You have to pay extra for every little feature. IMHO Sparx EA performs much better from this point of view. Has it's own flaws and problems of course.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yeah, maybe. But at least it does what TS wanted, maybe he can find better tool for his needs.